# Почему при .jpg цвет пикселя некорректно меняется?

Tags: java, файлы, изображения, io, jpeg

Вот ниже код моей программы:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ReadAndWriteImage
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File file = new File("I:\\TEST.jpg");

        BufferedImage image = null;

        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
            image.setRGB(20,1,8375);
            int clr = image.getRGB(2, 1);
            int red = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16; //cause 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
            int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8; //cause 1111 1111 0000 0000
            int blue = clr & 0x000000ff;

            System.out.println("Red Color value = " + red);
            System.out.println("Green Color value = " + green);
            System.out.println("Blue Color value = " + blue);

            //ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("I:/RESULT.jpg")); //некорректно работает!!!
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("I:/RESULT.png")); //работает корректно
            //ImageIO.write(image, "gif", new File("I:/RESULT.gif")); //работает корректно
            //ImageIO.write(image, "bmp", new File("I:/RESULT.bmp")); // работает корректно
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done");
    }
}
```

При использовании .jpg вместо синего пиксель рисуется черным. При .png  .gif .bmp рисуется правильно.

Вопрос: Почему так происходит? В смысле, в чем причина проблемы .jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что jpeg - это сжатие с потерями. Т.е., грубо говоря, в jpeg усредняется цвет близлежащих пикселей, исходя из утверждения, что человеческий глаз разницу все равно не заметит.

Таким образом говорить о цвете отдельного пикселя в формате jpeg нельзя.

К слову, именно поэтому изображения чувствительные к автоматической обработке (QR-коды, штрих-коды...) нельзя сохранять в формате jpeg

Comment: А как тогда к примеру программа microsoft paint легко сохраняет цвета такими какие они есть (конечно речь про .jpg) ну по крайней мере я не заметил заметной потери качества и особенно цвета после сохранения картинки. А насчет  "усредняется цвет близлежащих пикселей" ну тут вроде много цветов нет, поэтому как синий цвет усредняясь становится в прям черной - как то непонятно. Неужели настолько сильное допущение исходя из утверждения "человеческий глаз разницу все равно не заметит." ?